# How to alter .htaccess for the following url rewriting?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I go the url/[a 7 character alphanumeric string] for instance, localhost/delta/SW9NZ1p
or www.website.com/delta/SW9NZ1p, it should rewrite it as localhost/delta/product.php?url=SW9NZ1p or www.website.com/delta/product.php?url=SW9NZ1

Goal: While I'm viewing localhost/delta/SW9NZ1p I should see code executing from localhost/delta/product.php?url=SW9NZ1p but the url bar should show localhost/delta/SW9NZ1p

Can you tell me what's wrong with the following code?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^delta/([a-zA-Z0-9]{7,})/?$  product.php?url=$1    [NC,L]  
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Describe "isn't working"!

Comment: Can't get you. Can you elaborate?

Comment: http://htaccess.mwl.be/ claims that it should be working. Maybe the `mod_rewrite` module is not actually enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be getting not found error because apache might literally searching for `delta/as23221` if you are using the htaccess in root then use,

Try this in **delta** directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{7,})/?$ product.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

Try below in root,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{7,})/?$ delta/product.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I'm having .htacess file inside delta directory.

Comment: Then try with my second rewrite rule with conditions from first part.

Comment: What should I do if www.website.com/SW9NZ1p should be rewritten as www.website.com/delta/product.php?url=SW9NZ1p

Comment: You can dance, sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: If I go to the url www.website.com/SW9NZ1p, it should be rewritten internally as www.website.com/delta/product.php?url=SW9NZ1p . How to do this by altering the .htaccess file inside the delta directory?

Comment: You want redirect or rewriting, in redirect your url to browser will be changed in rewrite your url remain same and rewrite will happen internally which we are doing right now.

Comment: It should be done internally without changing the url in the browser (rewrite)

Comment: So this is what i did in my answer.

Comment: The answer you've written is for changing www.website.com/delta/SW9NZ1p to www.website.com/delta/product.php?url=SW9NZ1p . I'm asking how to change www.website.com/SW9NZ1p to www.website.com/delta/product.php?url=SW9NZ1p

Comment: That's working. I understood that. But how to change this?

Comment: Change to what?

Comment: The answer you've written is for rewriting www.website.com/delta/SW9NZ1p to www.website.com/delta/product.php?url=SW9NZ1p . I'm asking how to rewrite www.website.com/SW9NZ1p to www.website.com/delta/product.php?url=SW9NZ1p

Comment: Okay, you can tweak my same rule in root directory but you have to make some minor changes try for yourself if you get stuck ask a new question but I am sure you will get that.

Comment: I did this. But it is not working. I changed .htacess file inside delta directory to `RewriteRule ^../([a-zA-Z0-9]{7,})/?$ delta/product.php?url=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: Try this tool http://htaccess.mwl.be/ and use htaccess in root this time it is not that hard.

Comment: Kindly help me.

Comment: In root directory it is working fine. I used this in root directory RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{7})/?$ deltatask/snippet.php?url=$1 [NC,L] But how to use in delta directory

Comment: Try my first part in root directory, second part is for delta directory both rule are same.

Comment: You're not getting my point. I'm asking why this is not working RewriteRule ^../([a-zA-Z0-9]{7,})/?$ delta/product.php?url=$1 [NC,L] for rewriting www.website.com/SW9NZ1p to www.website.com/delta/product.php?url=SW9NZ1p  Kindly answer. I'm in urgent need of this

Comment: In the root I wrote that code. Its working. I'm asking how to write in delta folder instead of root

Comment: Delta director code isnt working. Only root code working